# Salesforce Licence Price depending on user profile

Tags: profile, pricing

I was wondering what is the price difference between A System Admin Profile a sales manger and a CEO profile.Any link from SalesForce will be helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Salesforce you pay for user licences.

The profile assigned to the user does not affect the cost of the user licence.

Answer (score 0):

Price is not for the profiles, it is related to the environment which you choose for your need.

http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/editions-pricing.jsp

You have to define the access privilege for each user type(CEO, Admin..) in the environment.